# How to combine number and string in batch file

Tags: windows, string, file, batch-file, join

I am using batch file to display some kind of number such as
00_test.txt 01_test.txt...10_test.txt 11_test.txt
Hence, This is my code. But I cannot show as my expectation

```
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,10) DO (
set "extension=.txt" 
set "fullname=%x%_test%extension%" 
echo.%fullname%
)
```

The result of above code are `_test.txt  _test_txt` but expected result are

```
00_test.txt 01_test.txt
```

Could you help me edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "baseName=_test"
    set "extension=.txt"

    for /l %%a in (1 1 10) do (
        set "n=0%%a"
        echo !n:~-2!%baseName%%extension%
    )
```

When a block of code (in your case the `for` and the code inside parenthesis) is reached by the parser, all variable reads are replaced with the value in the variable before starting to execute the code. So, if a variable is changed inside the block and the value needs to be retrieved inside the same block, it is necessary to use delayed expansion, telling the parser that variables that are referenced as `!var!` (instead of `%var%`), should not be replaced at parse time, its value should be accessed at execution time.

So, in this code `%baseName%` and `%extension%` are used with usual syntax as its value does not change inside the `for` code block, but `!n!` uses delayed expansion. Its value changes inside the block and this value must be accessed inside the same block.

The concatenation of a 0 prefix and the extraction of two characters on the right from the variable ensure the presence of the initial 0 for values 1 to 9

Answer (score 0):

Try `%%x` instead of `%x`:

```
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,10) DO (
set "extension=.txt" 
set "fullname=%%x%_test%extension%" 
echo.%fullname%
)
```

Comment: Did you try your code? It won't work.